# mshtml.dll version is 8.0 and Microsoft.mshtml is 7.0

Tags: mshtml, microsoft.mshtml

I'm a little confuse and maybe you can help me.

I've the mshtml.dll (version 8.0) and the Microsoft.mshtml.dll (version 7.0)

If I go to add a reference to my WPF project and try to add the mshtml.dll, it tells me that the reference has to be a valid assembly or com component. And that's right as I know I have to add a reference to Microsoft.mshtml.dll because it's mshtml.dll's wrapper, am I right?

Now, my mshtml.dll version is 8.0 and Microsoft.mshtml is 7.0.

Where can I found the 8.0 version of Microsoft.mshtml.dll?

If I add the 7.0 of the Microsoft.mshtml.dll it'll run the functions of the mshtml 8 dll?

Why are they different?

Thanks a lot for all, Jayson

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484791

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.mshtml is wrapped dll of mshtml.dll that's why you see the difference in version and this will be stored at( approximate location)

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office11\Microsoft.mshtml.dll
```

for ie-8 to ie-11 I am using Microsoft.mshtml 7.0.XXXX.XX dll without getting any problem.
but ie-11 not supports some of the functions of the dll.
let me know if you'll face any problem.

Yes, it will run your all functions without any problem except some functions